# Laravel9でのメール送信。.envファイルの設定の仕方。

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, mail, sendmail

**実現したいこと**

- 番号リストログインページの新規登録からメールアドレスとパスワードを登録し、メールの認証を行うためにメールを送信したい。
- ログインページでに「パスワードを忘れた」というボタンを押すと、メールアドレスを入力するページへ遷移し、メールアドレスを入力し、パスワードを再設定するリンクをメールで送信したい。

**前提**
LaravelのBreezeを使い、上記の実現したいことをしようとしています。

Laravel9の公式ドキュメントを元にメール認証とメールを使ったパスワード設定をやってみました。

・メール認証
https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/ja/verification.html
・パスワードのリセット
https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/ja/passwords.html

環境 : Laravel 9.52.0
PHP 8.0.26
Laravel/Breezeを以下の方法でインストール済み

```
$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev

$ php artisan breeze:install

$ npm install && npm run build
```

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
Connection could not be established with host "localhost:1025": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to localhost:1025 (Connection refused)
```

localhost:1025に繋がらないというエラーが返ってきます。

**該当のソースコード**
.envファイルのメール関係

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**試したこと**
MAIL_HOSTをmailpit、smtp.example.com
MAIL_PORTを465、587などに変えてみました。
自分がメールを送るために使っているサーバーが良くないのかと思っています。
お手数をおかけしますが、ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

ちゃんと動いてるメールサーバーありましたか？
あったら、その情報を`.env`に入れてみてください
例：

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=〇〇.xserver.jp
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=〇〇@company.jp
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=〇〇@company.jp
```

例えばメールサーバーはエックスサーバーを使ったら、接続方法はこちらのURLで確認できます。
[xserver](https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_mail_setting.php)